# window.onbeforeunload may fire multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

### Just because you don't see use for a feature doesn't mean it isn't useful.

The Stack Exchange network, GMail, Grooveshark, Yahoo! Mail, and Hotmail use the onbeforeunload prompt to prevent/warn users that they are leaving a page after they have begun editing something. Oh yah, **nearly every single desktop program** that accepts saveable user-input data utilizes this prompt-user-before-leaving UX pattern.

---

I have a function which behaves similarly to this one:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    // only prompt if the flag has been set... 
    if(promptBeforeLeaving === true){
        return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
    }
}
```

When a user attempts navigates away from the page the browser presents them with the option to leave or stay on the page. If the user selects the "Leave this page option" and then they quickly click on a link again before the page unloads completely the dialog fires again.

Are there any foolproof solutions to this problem?

---

Note: The following NOT the solution:

```
var alreadyPrompted = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    // only prompt if the flag has been set... 
    if(promptBeforeLeaving === true && alreadyPrompted === false){
        alreadyPrompted = true;
        return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
    }
}
```

because the user might select the "Stay on the page" option which would cause future `onbeforeunload`s to stop working.

Comment: please don't prompt people trying to leave your page. if they didn't want to leave it, they sure will after being asked.

Comment: @Nico, oh ye of limited insight. I dare you to begin answering this question then navigate away from the page.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of anything better than using a flag but also having a "mousemove" handler on the `<body>` or something that clears it.

Comment: @Pointy: I tried that, but the javascript executes for both "Stay on this Page" and "Leave the Page" events.

Comment: @David +1 for quotation. "oh ye of limited insight"

Comment: Well you mean that the "mousemove" handler fires after the "beforeunload" handler is done?

Comment: Pointy, yup. Or at least it does in Chrome 9.0.570.1 dev.   [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/isozo4/5/)

Comment: @Dave Murdoch - +1 on your question for pointing out that there *are* legitimate uses for this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this with a timer (`setInterval`) that starts in the `onbeforeunload` callback. Javascript execution will be paused while the confirm dialog is up, then if the user cancels out the timed function could reset the `alreadyPrompted` variable back to false, and clear the interval.

Just an idea.

Ok I did a quick test based on your comment.

```
<span id="counter">0</span>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   setInterval(function () { $('#counter').html(++counter); }, 1);
   return "are you sure?";
}
window.onunload = function () { alert($('#counter').html()) };
```

In between the two callbacks `#counter` never got higher than 2 (ms). It seems like using these two callbacks in conjunction gives you what you need.

**EDIT - answer to comment:**

Close. This is what i was thinking

```
var promptBeforeLeaving = true,
    alreadPrompted = false,
    timeoutID = 0,
    reset = function () {
        alreadPrompted = false;
        timeoutID = 0;
    };

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (promptBeforeLeaving && !alreadPrompted) {
        alreadPrompted = true;
        timeoutID = setTimeout(reset, 100);
        return "Changes have been made to this page.";
    }
};

window.onunload = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
};
```

Comment: This won't work as javascript execution continues for both "Stay on this Page" and "Leave the Page" events. The `alreadyPrompted` flag would be reset in both cases. Now, setting the timeout interval to a relatively high value (2 seconds, maybe?) to allow for page unload on slow connections should work in most cases...though it really isn't a perfect solution. If I do end up going with this I'll accept your answer.   Thanks!   :-)

Comment: It's all you can do. There is no possible way to tell for sure which button the user picked after `onbeforeunload` returns.

Comment: But bobince, I really, really want to. :-D. I wonder if I can do it with an iframe some how. BRB with my findings.

Comment: Couldn't get a dynamically created iframe's onbeforeunload to run. oh well.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell. Is [this](http://jsbin.com/uveno/5/) the implementation you were thinking of?

Comment: Interesting. The timeout's interval doesn't increment until after the dialog is closed. I guess that makes sense. I just didn't expect it.

Comment: right. that was the original assumption "Javascript execution will be paused while the confirm dialog is up"

Answer (score 1):

I have encapsulated the answers from above in an easy to use function:

```
function registerUnload(msg, onunloadFunc) {
    var alreadPrompted = false,
        timeoutID = 0,
        reset = function() {
            alreadPrompted = false;
            timeoutID = 0;
        };

    if (msg || onunloadFunc) { // register
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if (msg && !alreadPrompted) {
                alreadPrompted = true;
                timeoutID = setTimeout(reset, 100);
                return msg;
            }
        };

        window.onunload = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            if (onunloadFunc) onunloadFunc();
        };
    } else { // unregister
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.onunload = null;
    }
}
```

To register use:

```
registerUnload("Leaving page", function() { /* unload work */ });
```

To unregister use:

```
registerUnload();
```

Hope this helps ..