# Redirecting when user presses refresh button or back button

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-nonrel

Once user presses refresh or browser back button,then I want to redirect the user to one of the page for restart the application.My javaScript code is as follow:

```
var workIsDone = false;
window.onbeforeunload =confirmBrowseAway;
function confirmBrowseAway()
{
  if (!workIsDone) {
     alert("You are moving to choice page");
     window.location.href="/choice_page/";

  }
}
function abc(){
workIsDone=true;
}
//.
//.
<div align="center"><input class="button blue" type="Submit" value="Next" onClick="abc()"></div>
```

But I don't know why it is not working. I don't want to use confirm box.

Followup:
I have updated the code a bit. Its taking the user to choice page and asking to remain on the choice page or carry on with the work. But when user click OK to carry on the work, the last submitted data is again submitted.

```
  function confirmBrowseAway()
  {
     if (!workIsDone) {
      window.location.href="/choice_page/";
      return "Since you pressed refresh or back button, you are on start page again.";
     }
  }
```

Comment: What will you do when users accidently try to browse away, and want to click cancel? Just an alert is horrible usability.

Comment: @Stephen:The problem with giving user cancel button and giving him chance to carry on will give wrong result at the end and user will get nothing useful.Thats why I think instead of giving wrong result at the end, I should ask the user start the test again with warning not press refresh again.

Comment: Guys any suggestion..I hope it is not that much difficult as it seems to me.Thank you

Comment: If they cancel that doesn't mean the page is reloaded with the wrong data, it just means they won't leave it at all. Try typing an answer here on SO then click the back button, that's the kind of behhaviour you need, I think..

Comment: @ Stephan:No, the requirement is that either the user fully complete the whole work of application or start it again in case of refresh.As per your suggestion I have made some changes. But its re-submitting the last submitted data again in case when user carry on.Please have a look at my followup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some here and there changes in the solution [window.onbeforeunload may fire multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126820/window-onbeforeunload-may-fire-multiple-times) worked for me.
Thank you all,
Sunil Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it only works in IE (ie8 that I tested):

```
<script language="javascript">
function document.onkeydown() {
if (event.keyCode == 116) {
   alert("MOVING AWAY");
   window.location.href="/choice_page/"; 
   event.keyCode = 0; 
   event.cancelBubble = true; 
   return false; } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: My application will be used by users having different browsers. Hence I doubt this is suitable in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php) is how to detect the refresh

Comment: ábio:I think with window.onbeforeunload I can detect the refresh but the problem is that in case user select to carry on his work, last data is getting re-submitted.Any clue ?