# Getting onbeforeunload confirmation alert twice, when refreshing the URL?

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, dom-events

I am using the `window.onbeforeunload` for user confirmation, when user leaving the page, but confirmation alert happens twice only in IE.

My code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>User confirmation</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Used for confirmation , to closing the window */
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        return "Are you sure want to LOGOUT the session ?";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Folow the steps which I said in Stack overflow</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The scenario is ,

Step 1 : Run my code and open it in IE .

step 2 : After the application loads,close the browser window . You will get a confirmation alert.

step 3 : Give the **cancel** in the confirmation alert.

step 4 : Then refresh the URL by pressing the **ENTER button** in the address bar.

step 5 : Give **ok** in the alert.

step 6 : Now you will the confirmation alert once again.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try the timer workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design in IE.

Read the remarks where all the things that raise that event are listed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

you can use a timer to avoid this:

[window.onbeforeunload may fire multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126820/window-onbeforeunload-may-fire-multiple-times)